# Executor failed to create kernel. Unimplemented: Cast string to int64 is not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I was trying to train a local dataset of 306 images of food using the latest version of TensorFlow. However, when I tried to run it, it printed

> Train on 306 samples
>
> Epoch 1/5

at which point it just stopped doing anything so when I tried to run it in cmd I got the following error

```
Train on 306 samples
Epoch 1/5
2019-12-09 15:11:42.788897: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:642] Executor failed to create kernel. Unimplemented: Cast string to int64 is not supported
         [[{{node loss/activation_2_loss/Cast}}]]
```

I've looked at the code 100 times now and I can't seem to understand where I got it wrong and I couldn't find the solution on any other posts either.

**Now for the code**

I started off by loading the images, resizing them and assigning labels:

```
TRAIN_DIR = './food11/training'
class_names=['Bread', 'Dairy product', 'Dessert', 'Egg', 'Fried food', 'Meat']
def load_training_data(DIR):
    train_data = []
    for img in os.listdir(DIR):
        word_label = int(img.split('_')[0])
        label = class_names[word_label]
        path = os.path.join(DIR, img)
        if "DS_Store" not in path:
            img = Image.open(path)
            img = img.convert('L')
            img = img.resize((IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            train_data.append([np.array(img), label])

    shuffle(train_data)
    return train_data

train_data = load_training_data(TRAIN_DIR)
trainImages = np.array([i[0] for i in train_data]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE, 1)
trainLabels = np.array([i[1] for i in train_data])
```

I have then normalized the images and created a small model resulted with 6 neurons :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))


model.add(Dense(6))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))


model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                optimizer="adam",
                metrics=["accuracy"])


model.fit(trainImages, trainLabels, batch_size = 50, epochs = 5, verbose = 1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I believe it has to do with this line `train_data.append([np.array(img), label])` and the fact that label is a string. But it still doesn't help me fix it.

Comment: can you print out a few lines of this `train_data = load_training_data(TRAIN_DIR)`. like, `train_data[:3, :]` or `train_data.shape`

Answer (score 1):

The resolution to this problem is a small mistake regarding the "label".

```
word_label = int(img.split('_')[0])
label = class_names[word_label]
```

it returns trainLabels as strings (classes names instead of indexes), so I solved it by replacing the lines above with

```
label = int(img.split('_')[0])
```